# Find a specific entry in an ArrayList based upon another ArrayList?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have a product class

```
public class Produs {

private String denumire;
private String categorie;
private String taraOrigine;
private double pret;
}
```

with different constructors to fit my needs. I have an ArrayList of this type where all the Products have all the fields ( the list is generated by parsing a file ) . And another list in which there are products with only the name and country of origin filled ( rest of the fields are null ).This list is also generated from another list.

My question is , how can I search the first list, using the known fields of a product located in the second list , so that I can complete every object in the first list ?

I have tried with

```
public Produs getProdus(Produs p)
{
    for(Produs prod:produse)
        {
            if ((prod.getDenumire().equals(p.getDenumire()) && (prod.getTaraOrigine().equals(p.getTaraOrigine()))));
            {
                return prod;
            }
 }
return null;
}
```

where produse is my list of products where all fields have values and p is a Product constructed using only 2 fields.

I have also tried with overwriting equals and hashcode. The problem is that when it finds the element , the loop stops.

Comment: Yes loop will stop because you returned back to the caller with produs where you found your matching fields. So what you want to do post that?

Comment: When i have found a mathcing produs,I want to set the missing fields for all the produs in the list where i have null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to populate it before returning the actual object.

```
public Produs getProdus(Produs p)
{
    for(Produs prod:produse)
    {
        if ((prod.getDenumire().equals(p.getDenumire()) && (prod.getTaraOrigine().equals(p.getTaraOrigine()))));
        {
            if (prod.getCategorie() == null) {
                prod.setCategorie(p.getCategorie());//assuming you have getter and setter already in Produs
            }
            return prod;//remove this statement, if you want multiple products to be updated and make this method as void type instead of returning Produs type. Remove return null as well from end of this method.
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you want to list all the producs whose criteria matches then you could create a list and populate that like below:

```
public void getProdus(Produs p)
{
    List<Produs> productList = new ArrayList<Produs>();
    for(Produs prod:produse)
    {
        if ((prod.getDenumire().equals(p.getDenumire()) && (prod.getTaraOrigine().equals(p.getTaraOrigine()))));
        {
            productList.add(prod);
        }
    }
    for(Produs prod:productList) {//iterate over the list who matched the criteria and amend it with properties from p.
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. in my method Produs p(parameter give to method) is the produs with missing fields . I am trying to find a match in a list of Produs with all completed fields and then complete the mising fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your getProdus() function is correct. You need to call it in a loop for every object in the first list.

Comment: I am doing that 
for(ProdusCitit s: Gestiune.getInstance().getProduseCitite())
{
System.out.println(s);
Produs prod = new Produs(s.getDenumire(), s.getTaraOrigine());
System.out.println(Gestiune.getInstance().getProdus(prod));
   
}

The lists are stored in a singleton class "Gestiune". 
But when it finds the first element , the loop exits.

Comment: There is no reason for this loop to exit. Are you sure that getProduseCitite() returns a list with more than one element?

Comment: Yes , i am sure. The list returns 13 elements like this 
[denumire=Paine, categorie=null, taraOrigine=IT, pret=0.0, taxa=0.0, cantitate=2, magazin=MegaImage1, factura=Factura1]

I need to complete : categorie and other fields later on.

Comment: The loop retuns everytime the first element of the list where I have all fields filled in, instead of performing another search.